# Should I schedule Amazon Redshift cluster reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any benefit from rebooting a Redshift cluster?For example does the underlying ec2 get updated with newer resources or is this part of the automated maintenance(docs say the redshift  version is updated)?

Also, if I reboot a Redshift cluster should I expect downtime? How much time will this take to complete?

Comment: You should also consider that a restart will reset the cached queries and compiled plans. first run of queries after a restart will take considerably longer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not required. If the maintenance/update will result in downtime, AWS will let you know in advance.

Too keep your system healthy you might schedule tasks like vaccum, but you can have it running for several months without reboot.

An regarding how long it takes, it depends on your cluster size and when it is performed. You will learn it doing it. But the reboot doesn't take much time for small clusters.